# Super Search - {super_search_keywords} Not Parsing

Tags: supersearch

I have an instance where `{super_search_keywords}` wont parse. Everything else Parses fine and checking the documentation it is possible to use the tag outside of `{super_search:results}` - anyone have any ideas?

```
{super_search_total_results} Results found for {super_search_keywords}
{exp:super_search:results limit="50"}
    {title}
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, `{super_search_keywords}` won't parse outside the results loop, despite what SolSpace's documentation says.

Comment: This does seem to be the casee. To be fair the support was top notch and they got back to us within one working day. But in the end i made a plugin as a workaround.